# Does upgrading Internet Explorer improve overall system security if I don't use it?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

If I only use Chrome/Firefox/Opera on Windows, does upgrading IE to its latest version provide any benefit?

Imagine I have Windows 7 SP1 with the original IE and Microsoft offers a newer version for me.

Comment: Great question. I personally like to disable Internet Explorer completely- and instead keep Chrome fully up to date.

Answer (score 14):

Even if you aren't using Internet Explorer to browse the Internet, you definitely should keep it updated.  I wouldn't say you *have* to upgrade to the latest major version, but at least install the security patches for the version you are running, until it's no longer supported, then upgrade to a newer version.  I am a Chrome user, but there are some things that just work better with IE.  Personally, I always keep IE up to the latest version.

Internet Explorer is more than just a browser.  For good or bad, Internet Explorer is connected to the OS in many ways.  Programs called [HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)s, which the OS uses for a variety of interfaces, require Internet Explorer to function.  Some programs written with Visual Studio can use IE for built-in browsing and help.  There are many other functions that IE provides to other parts of the OS and applications.  Therefore, it's definitely best practice, at a minimum, to keep it patched.

Comment: MSIE provides an ActiveX (IIRC) control that implements the rendering engine, so I wouldn't be so sure it's only software written in Visual Studio which might use it (though Microsoft might "encourage" VS developers to use the IE "web browser" control rather than an alternative).

Comment: A very good summary of the issue. However, the suggestion that one could install security patches and only upgrade when a version goes EOL is not very useful. If you use MS Update (and it's impossible to keep up to date without it!), it's easier just to install each update as it appears, both patches and upgrades.